# One Anmation missed in ScrollView with scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to code a Auto Cycle Image player with UIScrollView.Then I code this method :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_scrollView.contentOffset.x+230, 0);
}];
```

This method run but couldn’t play well just move without animation while my scrollView have scrollViewDidScroll delegate Method.
what’s wrong with it ?So disturb me. thank you fisrt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write as:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:totalImageCount target:self selector:@selector(animateImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 - (void)animateImages 
   {
       [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame), 0.0) animated:YES];
   }
```